# How to send a PIN verification CODE to a smartcard using APDU - Using .NET

Tags: .net, smartcard, asp.net-4.5, apdu

I am able to connect to the card and now I need to verify the PIN but I´m not able to figure out which code should I use to perform the verification

```
// Verify PIN
//HERE IS WHAT I´M NOT SURE WHAT TO USE - Just an Example
byte[] pin = new byte[] { 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF };
APDUParam apduParam = new APDUParam();
apduParam.Data = pin;
apduVerifyCHV.Update(apduParam);
apduResp = iCard.Transmit(apduVerifyCHV);
```

It is a smart card that uses an 7 digits PIN. It is always 7 digits.

```
**Example:**
{CLA, INS, P1, P2, Lc, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7}
```

Here I have the basic `CLA`, `INS`, `P1`, `P2`, `LC` bytes. 
Should I set + 3 bytes or 6 bytes for the PIN of 7 digits
And shall be the actual PIN or just a 0xFF value

```
Ex. {CLA, INS, P1, P2, Lc, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xFF} +7 Bytes
```

in the spec I found examples for 8 Digits min and max and min 4 and max 12 bytes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simpler than I tought...

**When PIN uses ASCII format conversion with padding**

PIN entered is 1357 (min size =4 and max size=8 digits)

- • Left justification
- • Default display behavior for the CCID
- • The CCID sends to the ICC the command

  CLA INS P1 P2 Lc 31 33 35 37 FF FF FF FF

**When PIN uses BCD right justification and control field**

PIN entered is 13579 (min size =4 and max size=8 digits)

- • Right justification. The personal code contains less than 8 digits;
  therefore, the most  significant digits of the eight-digit code must
  be filled with zeroes.
- • The frame integrates a specific control field “01” before the PIN
  conversion.
- • No messages
- • The CCID sends to the ICC the command

  CLA INS P1 P2 Lc 01 00 01 35 79

so, all I had to do was to set the proper values. 
In my case using ASCII method with left justification:

```
0x00 0x20 0x00 0x01 0x08 0x30 0x31 0x34 0x37 0x34 0x31 0x30 0xFF
```

3  - refers to the padding

3x - x refers to the actual pin number at a given position (left justification) 
as I have a PIN of 7 digits the bytes not used shall default to 0xFF

Hope that helps some one

Comment: It is quite uncommon, that the host application has to perform  a padding, since typically the valid character set is not restricted and 0xFF would be a legal character. Also the maximum length is not necessarily known outside. If only digits are permitted,  ISO 9564 defines some variants.

Comment: Hi, can anyone provide the reference of standards which has **Verify PIN** and **Verify ADM** commands? Is it in **ETSI** or **ISO** or **3GPP**?

Comment: @Ac3_DeXt3R ISO/IEC 7816-4. It's behind a $170 USD paywall.